# Phone numbers aren't links in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: cti, hyperlink

I have written a 3rd-party call center for Salesforce using the Open CTI API. In Chrome and Firefox, contacts' phone numbers are clickable links. In Internet Explorer 11, they are not. I don't see any error in the console that appears to be relevant, so I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [CTI Admin Cheat Sheet](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/202/14/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_cti_admin_cheatsheet.pdf), notably:

> The minimum system requirements for a CTI adapter are:
>
> • For adapters built with CTI version 4.0 or higher:
>
> – Microsoft® Internet Explorer® 8; Mozilla® Firefox® 3.5; Apple® Safari® 4; Google Chrome™ 10.0 **(Internet Explorer 11 isn’t supported)**
>
> – Microsoft Windows®
> XP (with Microsoft .NET framework)

(Emphasis added.)

The sweet spot for Internet Explorer support is IE 10. Lower versions might not work with all features, and 11 doesn't work with all features.

Comment: It's been a while since I've come across something to renew my confirmation bias that Internet Explorer is generally unfit for exploring the internet (or navigating your previously explored net-scape, for that matter). Good to know that my animosity towards IE remains at least somewhat justified.

Comment: @DerekF http://gs.statcounter.com/ -- most of the world seems to agree with you.